# Using IBM Watson Speech-to-Text with react-mic issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

Im traying to use react-mic to get an audio file and send to watson speech-to-text service but when i get the audio blob file and send in a post request to watson im getting the next error:

```
error   "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 13: invalid start byte"
```

Anyone knows why i'm getting that error? im not sure what is the problem, this is my implementation code:

```
export const speechToText = async (file) =>{

    const formData = new FormData();
    let fileName = 'speech.webm';
    formData.append(fileName, file.blob);


    await Axios.post('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize',
                formData, {
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
                  },
                  auth:{
                    username: 'apikey',
                    password: '######'
                  }
                }).then(  (response) => {
                  console.log('SUCCESS!!');
                  console.log(response);

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  console.log('FAILURE!!');
                });
}
```

Component react:

```
...

<ReactMic
                    record={this.state.record}
                    className="sound-wave"
                    onStop={this.onStop}
                    onData={this.onData}
                    strokeColor="#000000"
                    backgroundColor="#FF4081"
                    mimeType="audio/webm"
                    channelCount={1} />
...

async onStop(recordedBlob) {
        console.log('recordedBlob is: ', recordedBlob);
        speechToText(recordedBlob);
      }
```